# How can I reuse another classes' method without inheritance in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Two of my classes need to have the same method, but they are not related by inheritance.

The following works in Python 3:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'A'

    def printmyx(self):
        print(self.x)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'B'

    printmyx = A.printmyx

a = A()
b = B()

a.printmyx()
b.printmyx()
```

and prints

```
A
B
```

However, in Python 2 I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py2test.py", line 18, in <module>
    b.printmyx()
TypeError: unbound method printmyx() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I think the problem is that in Python 3 `printmyx` is just a regular function while in Python 2 it's an unbound method.

How to make the code work in Python 2?

**edit**

In my real code, `A` and `B` inherit from different parent classes. They need to share one helper method but have no other relation to each other.

Comment: You could try to just create the function on class B and then activate the function on class A?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, I'd just "pull" the implementation of that method (here, `A.printmyx`) out of the class, put it in a helper function (e.g. `def _printmyx(instance): ...` and call that helper function from each of your classes: `def printmyx(self): return _printmyx(self)`

Comment: @jedwards Thanks, that's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in Python 2 the original function an unbound method was created from is stored in the `im_func` attribute.<sup>1</sup>

To make the code work in Python 2 like it does in Python 3, use

```
printmyx = A.printmyx.im_func
```

in `B`'s body.

<sup>1</sup> Described in the [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)
section of the Python 2 Data Model documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that Python does support multiple inheritance, so it's very possible to define a mixin class and have both A and B inherit from it without disturbing the main inheritance hierarchy. I understand you're saying the classes have little in common - but they do both have a variable called x and a method to print it - and to me at least, that's enough in common to consider using inheritance.

But that said, another way to do this is using a class decorator to add the common method:

```
def add_printmyx(original_class):
    def printmyx(self):
        print (self.x)
    original_class.printmyx = printmyx
    return original_class

@add_printmyx
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'B'

b = B()
b.printmyx()
```

The class decorator takes the original class and adds (or replaces) a printmyx method that prints the contents of x.

Comment: Thanks. I considered a Mixin but did not want to whip out multiple inheritance for such a seemingly trivial problem. Didn't think of the class decorator. +1

Answer (score -1):

Why is inheritance not allowed? This is the perfect use case for inheritance.

```
class Common(object):
    def printmyx(self):
        print(self.x)

class A(Common):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'A'

class B(Common):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'B'

a = A()
b = B()

a.printmyx()
b.printmyx()
```

Comment: Because in my actual code the classes share no relation besides the need to share a simple helper method and inherit from different parent classes.

Comment: But the helper method references an instance variable. I'm not sure how you expect to share that logic without using some sort of inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I suspect that the code you posted is not your actual code.

Comment: as you can see it's perfectly possible in Python 3